# Async problem in Angular 13 Custom Pipe when i call service within pipe

Tags: angular, asynchronous, pipe

I have more pipe in template

```
{{someItems | async | pipe1 | filterpipe}}
```

My problem is: The myservice service make lot of things(its run in ngoninit and and call backendservices) it take some time and when I in pipe want to check it in if statement will be always false.Its an async problem. I tried with impure pipe but i got lot of rerender and application froze and in top of that the `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` error as well. How can i achive it to wait till that myservice get a correct value?

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { MyService } from '../myservice';

@Pipe({
name: 'filter',
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
     constructor(private myService: MyService) {}

     transform(items: any[], searchTerm: any, searchBy: string) {
                  //Here is the problem
       if (this.myService.getValue) {
          return items.filter((item) => item.desc === 'AA');
 


        // when there is partial or full match of the search term
        return items.filter((item) => {
          const currentItem = item[searchBy];
          return currentItem
            .toString()
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(searchTerm.trim().toLowerCase());
           });
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this.myService.getValue return ? It looks like a function but it has no parenthesis

Comment: Its just return a boolean based on what kind of data come from backend.Not the parantheses the problem

Comment: Where is the async call?

Comment: Little bit complicated.In a compontent oninit happend and an other component get it through input and i have a service that have a Behavior subject that default false and in this componenet should true be.And this service in the pipe.But pipe run faster than this service get a value